# WPF wrong binding but CollectionView still filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, collectionviewsource

I wrote a simple code to allow filtering on my datagrid, but I made a mistake in my code. But it still work as expected.

Here is what I did:

1. Gettings the source items (from the database)
2. Creating the `ICollectionView` from it
3. Setting my custom filter
4. Binding the **source** to the DataGrid instead of the *view*

The 4th point is where I made my mistake. I should have bound the **view** to the DataGrid, not the *source*, right?

Here is the code:

```
var mySources = GettingMySource();

var myView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(mySources);
myView.Filter = MyFilter;

DataGrid.ItemsSource = mySources;
```

Somewhere else in my code (when the user enter a filter), I just call:

```
myView.Refresh();
```

And it works... The elements that don't match with my filter are removed from the CollectionView and from the UI, but my source list is unchanged...

Can someone explain me how this can work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> All collections have a default CollectionView. WPF always binds to a view rather than a collection. If you bind directly to a collection, WPF actually binds to the default view for that collection. This default view is shared by all bindings to the collection, which causes all direct bindings to the collection to share the sort, filter, group, and current item characteristics of the one default view.

So it seems that while you tell the DataGrid to use the source, it still automatically takes the (default) view which is shared over all bindings and has your filter applied to it.

#### edit:

it also says that

> This default view is never affiliated with any CollectionViewSource objects.

So, it would not have filtered if you had applied the filter to the `View` of a `new CollectionViewSource(mySources)` instead of the default view.

Comment: I have no idea about that default CollectionView in all collections. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

> I should have bound the view to the DataGrid, not the source, right?

Yes. The CollectionView is a layer between your collection and the DataGrid. It allows you to navigate, sort, filter and group the items in your collection **without actually modifying your original collection**. So the line `DataGrid.ItemsSource = mySources;` is wrong, you should bind it to `myView` instead.

> The elements that don't match with my filter are removed from the
>   CollectionView and from the UI, but my source list is unchanged...

If your goal is to get the list of filtered items from your CollectionView, you should use [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var filteredData = myView.Cast<Entity>()
```

Comment: I don't have any specific goal other than understanding how it works. @wkl explains why : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41281129/2183236